# Embedding SMO dlls in Setup and deployment

Tags: .net, deployment, installation

I have a .NET Set and Deployment project which has to execute a set of really long SQL Scripts as a part of the installation process. I have used SMO dlls to make calls to the .sql script files.These SMO dlls are however not a part of the .NET framework but they come bundled with SQL Server 2005 or 2008. Now, if the setup is run on a machine which does not have SQL Server 2005/2008 installed the SQL script execution fails. This is a perfectly valid use case for my setup as the user might not have SQL server on his local machine but on a network server.
How do i embedd the SMO dll's along with the setup .msi so that it doesnt have to depend on any SMO dlls on the machine it is being run?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to add those files to the deployment project.

If you right click on the project in solution explorer then select View > File System you could add those files under the target machine's application folder.

If you need to register the dll's I think you can add a custom action to do that, but I'm not sure.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Zachary. But the thing is that I want to use the SMO dlls from the CustomInstaller class of the msi itself.Copying the dlls to the application root still doesn't give the Custominstaller class the reference it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I didn't understand the question at first glance.  I would do the following:

1. Create a custom installer project (Class Library)
2. Add a reference to the SMO DLLs (I think you have to set Copy Local = True)
3. Add an installer class to it with your sql deployment logic
4. Add this project's output to your setup project
5. Setup the necessary custom actions

[This article](http://www.codeguru.com/Csharp/.NET/net_security/encryption/article.php/c9601/) explains a similar process (minus the SMO calls), it's based on [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk.aspx).

Hope that helps!