# Executing SQL scripts with GO statements without SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, smo

One thing I’m having problems with, is deploying app to machine not having SMO installed on it. I want to execute scripts having `GO`statements, but also would like to avoid the need for installing SMO package on a target machine or parsing SQL script file (since I don't know if sql script will contain functions or SPs).

I tried manually copying SMO relevenat dlls to bin folder of executable but there are always some other dlls needed to run the app.

Any help with this?

Comment: You need to provide much more detail about what you are trying to do,  your expected result, and your specific issue.

Comment: Why do you want to use GO statements?

Comment: I have MSSQL scripts I need to execute, but don't know their format and have to support executing scripts that contain GO statement

Comment: `GO` is just an indicator to split up scripts. Why not take the query text, split it into an array or collection of your choosing with `GO` as the separator, then iterate through running each script in turn?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to SMO, the [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) utility can understand GO statements.  You will need to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` in order to call out to it with your script as an argument.

<sub>By no means am I saying this is ***the*** way to do it, but it is a valid alternative. You still have the same issues as before if the utility doesn't exist on the target machine.</sub>

You might also be able to deploy SMO with the installer package without "installing" it on the target machine:

[Embedding SMO dlls in Setup and deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305291/embedding-smo-dlls-in-setup-and-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

I find below solution well tested

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    try
    {
      cn.Open();
      FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);
      string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
      string[] splitChar = { "\r\nGO\r\n" };
      var sqlLines = script.Split(splitChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      int res = 0;
      SqlCommand cmd = null;
      foreach (var query in sqlLines)
      {
          cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn)
          {
              CommandTimeout = 5400
          };
          res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      cn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      msg = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
      cn.Close();
    }
  }
```